Online value and physical value does not populate using Laravel and JS
I'm working on code to populate the input boxes with data. When a user clicks the button, the code must populate and show the data. However, the problem is that it does not populate the physical value and online value. Only the selected key is populated.
<div class="container p-5">
  <h2><b>Utilization</b></h2>
  <button class="btn btn-primary rounded-css mt-3" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#addUtilizationModal">Add New Data</button>

  <div class="container mb-3">
    <div class="mb-3 mt-2 col-md-3 text-center">
      <div class="btn-group " role="group">
      @foreach ($utilizationData as $utilization)
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary utilization-button"
                onclick="populateUtilization('{{ $utilization->key }}', '{{ $utilization->physical_value }}', '{{ $utilization->online_value }}')">
          {{ $utilization->key }}
        </button>
      @endforeach

      </div>
    </div>

    <form action="/updateUtilYear" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      @csrf
      <input id="selectedKey" name="selectedKey">
      <div class="row mb-3">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="physicalValue">Physical Value</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="physicalValue" name="physicalValue" required>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="onlineValue">Online Value</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="onlineValue" name="onlineValue" required>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>

JS:
function populateUtilization(selectedKey, physicalValue, onlineValue) {
  document.getElementById('selectedKey').value = selectedKey;
  document.getElementById('physicalValue').value = physicalValue;
  document.getElementById('onlineValue').value = onlineValue;

  // Debug: Check the values after setting them in the input boxes
  console.log('After setting values - Selected Key:', selectedKey);
  console.log('After setting values - Physical Value:', physicalValue);
  console.log('After setting values - Online Value:', onlineValue);
}

Looking forward to your insights.

Do values appear in your onclick when you inspect the button? Does onclick="populateUtilization(... have all the values?

it has. the data shows on the console
After setting values - Selected Key: 2025  After setting values - Physical Value: 1  After setting values - Online Value: 2
